# Can I send and receive iMessage on Mac without buying an iPhone?

Tags: macos, mac, messages

I have an Apple ID.

Macbook Air has iMessage installed.

But I cannot figure why I cannot send and receive iMessage to friends.
I can only receive messages from myself.

Can you explain how iMessage will work on Mac?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my question myself.

This is easy to have a try. You can send an receive iMessage when you are online. To send a message, you only need to set the receiving address an `Apple ID`, or some phone numbers related to the ID. Of course, you network must be well enough to connect to `apple`.